# Not able to make a virtual environment using virutalenv and virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I was trying to make a virtual environment called rango. Here's what I did:

Inside the directory where virtualenvwrapper.sh is  present  :

```
~/.local/bin$ source virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Now when I am trying to make virtual environment using

```
~/.local/bin$ mkvirtualenv rango
```

It gives me the following error :

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /home/kartikey/.virtualenvs/rango/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /home/kartikey/.virtualenvs/rango/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /home/kartikey/.virtualenvs/rango/bin/python2 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel:
  Collecting setuptools
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/home/kartikey/.virtualenvs/rango/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kartikey/.virtualenvs/rango/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/kartikey/.virtualenvs/rango/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kartikey/.virtualenvs/rango/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/home/kartikey/.virtualenvs/rango/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/kartikey/.virtualenvs/rango/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/kartikey/.virtualenvs/rango/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 315, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2375, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 724, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 992, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 922, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 817, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/kartikey/.virtualenvs/rango/bin/python2 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 2
```

I am completely stuck, I am not able to understand what is the error and how do get past through it?

Comment: What are your versions of python, pip, setuptools?

Comment: I got very similar problem here, what I got is a 404 `HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/pkg-resources/.` However I found that there is no `simple/pkg-resources` directory under any pypi mirror, so how may I fix this?